# Search in one query when params are nil?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, psql

I wish to have only one query, but my problem is that when some params are nil, it will return no results, while I want it to return all. See code:

```
deliverer_ids = params[:deliverer_ids]&.map(&:to_i) || []
shopper_ids   = params[:shopper_ids]&.map(:to_i) || []
@orders       = @orders.includes(:deliverer, :shopper).where(deliverer_id: deliverer_ids, shopper_id: shopper_ids)
```

will return nothing and what I want to achieve is to get `Order.all` if params `deliverer_ids` and `shopper_ids` are nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as I am sure you understand, that if e.g. `deliverer_ids` is missing, you are requiring that `deliverer_id` is one of... no IDs. No rows will match that, even if you specify valid IDs in `shopper_ids`.

Untested but I'm thinking this should work, if you change `deliverer_ids` to `deliverer_id`:

```
conditions = params
    .slice(:deliverer_id, :shopper_id)
    .map { |x| x.map(&:to_i) }
@orders = @orders.includes(:deliverer, :shopper).where(conditions)
```

If you don't rename them, then you have a bit more of a hassle.

The idea is not to pass the conditions you don't have. ActiveSupport's `slice` allows you to just keep parameters you want, then deliver them directly to `where` as conditions.

EDIT: Easier, and no need for renaming: just use `compact`:

```
deliverer_ids = params[:deliverer_ids]&.map(&:to_i)
shopper_ids = params[:shopper_ids]&.map(:to_i)
conditions = {
  deliverer_id: deliverer_ids,
  shopper_id: shopper_ids
}.compact
@orders = @orders.includes(:deliverer, :shopper).where(conditions)
```

Note the removal of the damaging `|| []` bit. In fact, I didn't test, but it may even work with your original code, as long as you drop that bit - ActiveRecord might be smart enough to not include any restrictions if the restriction is `nil`.